Word 'between' for things like values in range - exclusive/inclusive
Is there any single word that could be used in pair with the word 'between' where the other word is either exclusive or inclusive? Exclusivity is generally dependent on context, with inclusive being default in most cases, if I took a correct guess.
I need only one if there is at least that single one, I take even archaic English if there is one, ore creative new word.
I am picking name for a type in programming library and:
Value_Between - great
Value_Between_Inc - not horrible but would prefer between alternative
Value_Between_Exc - not horrible but would prefer between alternative

Picking final name: Value_Between - this will be assigned inclusive or exclusive if only one fitting word is found, if both, than depending on better sounding/fitting to the pair. The companion name will be then Value_(amazing_word_I_did_never_hear).
Pair without word between would suffice as well, of course, but I doubt there is any.

...the answer on the linked duplicate claims that only American English has the inclusive "through", but that's ridiculous. If you use "through" to indicate an inclusive range, obviously Brits will understand it. But there is no unambiguous term for an exclusive range, so far as I know.

Thank you, completely forgot this word, that is what I wanted.
